# Resize multiple images with imagemagick from a folder to other (and keep the name) with a command

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-processing

Let's say that the images are in the directory `/Desktop/projs/proj1/img/` and I want the output files to go to `/Desktop/projs/proj1/imgResized/`.

I tried this command:

```sh
convert /Desktop/projs/proj1/img/*.png -resize 130x130\! /Desktop/projs/proj1/imgResized/converted.png
```

This works, but the output images are renamed to `converted-0.png`, `converted-1.png`, etc.

I tested other commands to see if the images keep their names:

```sh
for PHOTO in /Desktop/projs/proj1/img/*.png; do BASE=`basename $PHOTO` convert /Desktop/projs/proj1/img/*.png -resize 130x130 /Desktop/projs/proj1/imgResized/$BASE.png; done;
```

But it’s not working.

How can I do this? And if possible, how can I do the same but for compressing all the images from folder A to B?

Comment: Your second code is wrong it should be `convert "$PHOTO" `. The for variable should be used.

Comment: And I see that you have `/Desktop` that directory does not exist except you created else it should have been `/home/$USER/Desktop`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```sh
for i in /home/$USER/Desktop/projs/proj1/img/*.png; do 
    convert "$i" -resize 130X130 "/home/$USER/Desktop/projs/proj1/imgResized/${i##*/}"
done
```

should work, modify.

Comment: $i includes /Desktop/projs/proj1/img/

Comment: "$i" are the individual files in that folder `img`!

Comment: Try this >>  for i in ~/Desktop/projs/proj1/img/*.png; do echo $i; done

Comment: Your point @Vijay?

Comment: posted the command line

Comment: should work, modify ???

Comment: Thanx for the edit works now.

Answer (score 2):

Fewer keystrokes:

```
 for i in ~/Desktop/projs/proj1/img/*.png; do convert "$i" -resize 130X130 "${i/img/imgResized}"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to 2023!  Surprised mogrify was not mentioned in connection with imagemagick.

Assuming the imgResized directory already exists, the below should work fine from the directory containing the original images, *and* keep the original names.  No loops necessary.

```
mogrify -resize 130x130 -quality 100 -path ~/Desktop/projs/proj1/imgResized/ *.png
```